# Dropdown menu does not stay selected as intended

Tags: python

I my code, where I have 3 dropdown menus dependend on each other, middle menu does not keep the value selected. Everything else works as intended, that means, if I select Option1 for an example in main menu, sub menu should have options aaaa and bbbb and then sub sub menu keeps me select from 1111 and 2222 accordingly.

```
import tkinter as tk

def run():
    main_menu_item = main_menu_var.get()
    sub_menu_item = sub_menu_var.get()
    sub_sub_menu_item = sub_sub_menu_var.get()
    
    print("Main Menu Item:", main_menu_item)
    print("Sub Menu Item:", sub_menu_item)
    print("Sub Sub Menu Item:", sub_sub_menu_item)

def update_sub_menu(*args):
    sub_menu_var.set("")  # Clear sub menu selection
    sub_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')  # Clear sub menu options
    sub_sub_menu_var.set("")  # Clear sub sub menu selection
    sub_sub_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')  # Clear sub sub menu options
    
    selected_option = main_menu_var.get()
    if selected_option in submenus:
        for item in submenus[selected_option]:
            sub_menu['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=lambda value=item: update_sub_sub_menu(selected_option, value))


def update_sub_sub_menu(main_menu_item, sub_menu_item):
    sub_sub_menu_var.set("")  # Clear sub sub menu selection
    sub_sub_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')  # Clear sub sub menu options
    
    if main_menu_item in submenus and sub_menu_item in submenus[main_menu_item]:
        for item in sub_submenus[sub_menu_item]:
            sub_sub_menu['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=lambda value=item: sub_sub_menu_var.set(value))


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Menu Example")

# Main Menu
main_menu_var = tk.StringVar(root)
main_menu_options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
main_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, main_menu_var, *main_menu_options, command=update_sub_menu)
main_menu.config(width=10)  # Set width to 10
main_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Sub Menu
sub_menu_var = tk.StringVar(root)
sub_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, sub_menu_var, "")
sub_menu.config(width=10)  # Set width to 10
sub_menu.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Sub Sub Menu
sub_sub_menu_var = tk.StringVar(root)
sub_sub_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, sub_sub_menu_var, "")
sub_sub_menu.config(width=10)  # Set width to 10
sub_sub_menu.grid(row=0, column=2)

# Submenu items
submenus = {
    "Option 1": ["aaaa", "bbbb"],
    "Option 2": ["cccc", "dddd"],
    "Option 3": ["eeee", "ffff"]
}

# Sub-submenu items
sub_submenus = {
    "aaaa": ["1111", "2222"],
    "bbbb": ["3333", "4444"],
    "cccc": ["5555", "6666"],
    "dddd": ["7777", "8888"],
    "eeee": ["9999", "1010"],
    "ffff": ["11aa", "12aa"]
}

# Run Button
run_button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=run)
run_button.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do that.

The middle menu doesn't keep its selected value because the sub_menu_var isn't updated with a value from the newly loaded options.
To fix this:

- Update sub_menu_var with the first item of the new options inside update_sub_menu.
- Just add new items to the sub-menu, set sub_menu_var to the first item to ensure it has a default selection.
- Call update_sub_sub_menu with the first item of the sub-menu to update the sub-sub menu.

Here is the code to do that.

```py
def update_sub_menu(*args):
    sub_menu_var.set("") 
    sub_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end') 
    sub_sub_menu_var.set("") 
    sub_sub_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    
    selected_option = main_menu_var.get()
    if selected_option in submenus:
        first_item = None
        for item in submenus[selected_option]:
            if first_item is None:
                first_item = item
            sub_menu['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=lambda value=item: update_sub_sub_menu(selected_option, value))
        
        if first_item:
            sub_menu_var.set(first_item)
            update_sub_sub_menu(selected_option, first_item)
```

Let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This modification only selects the first item in submenu, but does not allow me to select another.